# Combining two functions in LISP to atomize list and then find max?

Tags: function, lisp

So, id like to take in a list of numbers, atomize it (to remove nested integers), then find the max value.  I have two functions written that accomplish this individually, but can't figure out how to combine them in LISP so I can make one call and have them both run. Any help would be appreciated.

```
:Atomize function to remove nests 
:(atomify ‘( a (b c) (e (f (g h) i)) j)->(a b c e f g h i j)

(defun atomify (numbers)
  (cond ((null numbers) nil)
        ((atom (car numbers))
         (cons (car numbers)
               (atomify (cdr numbers))))
        (t
         (append (atomify (car numbers))
                 (atomify (cdr numbers))))))



:Max value of a list of integers function

(defun large_atom (numbers) 
  (if (null numbers)
      0 
      (max (first numbers)
           (large_atom (rest numbers)))))
```

Comment: I would propose to make your code readable for humans by indentation and better formatting.

Comment: Your functions already combine other functions. Why shouldn't that work for atomify and large_atom, too?

Comment: Apologies about the formatting, Ill look up the proper way to format lisp and edit it.

Comment: I want to give large_atom a list of numbers, but de-nest the list from inside large_atom.  Im de-nesting the list through recursion with Atomify, and dont know exactly how to call Atomify from large_atom, or if its even possible in lisp?

Comment: Your `large_atom` function is incorrect for, for instance `(-1)`.

Comment: I appreciate the pointer, but this is homework, so no negative numbers will be used.

Comment: If you have two functions A and B, and B should work on the results of A: (B (A some-data))

Comment: And it does, but the instructor wanted us to write one function that would flatten the list and return the max value.  I wrote two for testing purposes, and thought combing them would be simple, but it is not.  I can't seem to find any information online about how I can do this.

Comment: You should look at your function ATOMIFY and check how you can modify it, so that it does not return a list, but a maximum...

Comment: Thats what ive been trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: But that's simple. Read what I said: 'so that it does not return a list, but a maximum'. Check ATOMIFY, where it returns lists and see what to return instead...

Comment: Thanks for the tips Rainer, but im completely lost.  This is for programming languages, and we are spending a week on uncommon languages, and this week is LISP.   I don't understand the syntax and cant figure out where max would go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamie. Your way has two steps:
1. Flatten list
2. Find max value from result of 1'st step
In this case it's true way. But you need do it with one function call. It's easy. Just use [labels](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_flet_.htm), [apply](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm) and of course [max](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_max_m.htm)

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (labels ((flatten (lst acc)
             (cond
               ((null lst)
                acc)
               ((consp (car lst))
                (flatten (cdr lst) (flatten (car lst) acc)))
               (t
                (flatten (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc))))))
    (apply #'max (flatten lst nil))))
```

Another way, is do not flatten source list. But in this case you need find first value to compare with other values. Try it yourself.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but Im having trouble following your code here.  When I try to run it, it tells me foo has no value?

Comment: you need call `foo` with args. For example `(foo '(1 2 3 (3 4 (4 3) 2 3) ((2 3 2) 1)))`.

Comment: I tried that, but I'll try it again when I get home.  Thanks again for the responses!

Comment: Due to a syntax error completely on my part, and now that thats fixed, it runs great!  Thank you very much Hurry Bob

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to solve the problem: rather than flattening the list, this walks down it recursively.  This is very explicit about what the structure of the list must be: a good list is a non-null proper list each of whose elements is either an integer or a good list.

The problem with this approach is that it's not tail recursive so it will necessarily fail on very large structures (and even if it was tail recursive CL does not promise to deal with tail recursion.

```
(defun greatest-integer (good-list)
  ;; a good list is one of:
  ;; - a cons of a good list and either a good list or ()
  ;; - a cons of an integer and either a good list or ()
  ;; In particular it can't be () and it can't be an improper list
  ;;
  (destructuring-bind (a . b) good-list
    ;; a can be an integer or a good list, b can be null or a good list
    (etypecase b
      (null
       (etypecase a
         (integer a)
         (cons (greatest-integer a))))
      (cons
       (max (etypecase a
              (integer a)
              (cons (greatest-integer a)))
            (greatest-integer b))))))
```